# golang helloworld prints weird error message

Tags: go

I tried to run a helloworld program but failed. This is the content in `helloworld.go`:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

command `go run helloworld.go` prints this weird error message:

```
panic: runtime error: makeslice: len out of range

goroutine 8 [running]:
debug..z2felf.Section.Data
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/debug/elf/file.go:105
buildid.readGccgoArchive
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/cmd/internal/buildid/buildid.go:150
buildid.ReadFile..func1
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/cmd/internal/buildid/buildid.go:67
cmd..z2finternal..z2fbuildid.ReadFile
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/cmd/internal/buildid/buildid.go:85
cmd..z2fgo..z2finternal..z2fwork.Builder.useCache
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/work/buildid.go:547
cmd..z2fgo..z2finternal..z2fwork.Builder.build
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/work/exec.go:374
work.func1
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/work/exec.go:107
work.func2
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/work/exec.go:165
created by cmd..z2fgo..z2finternal..z2fwork.Builder.Do
    ../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgo/go/cmd/go/internal/work/exec.go:152 +2227
```

The output of `go version` is:
`go version go1.12.2 gccgo (GCC) 9.2.0 linux/amd64`

This is the output of `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/user1/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user1/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/user1/local"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/home/user1/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0"
GCCGO="/home/user1/local/bin/gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build838223013=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -funwind-tables"
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks

Comment: There’s something wrong with your gccgo install. Why are you using gccgo at all? Try the official install and current version of go.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. After installing the go from official website, it works.